# Vue 2.X - Good approach towards waiting for contrasting async data sources in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, promise, vue-component

Within a Vue component I have two async calls for data from different sources (one a HTTP call, one a browser cache call) and I want to have a loader spin until both are complete. When both are complete the component is loaded so to speak.

```
...
data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    }
},
mounted: function() {
    this.getData(); // HTTP Async API
    this.getOtherData(); // IndexedDB Async API 
},
...
```

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to set loading to false when both return data. My current approach of using flags looks dirty but I'm not sure if its the best approach.

```
...
data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      flagA: false,
      flagB: false
    }
},
mounted: function() {
    this.getData(); // HTTP Async API
    this.getOtherData(); // IndexedDB Async API 

},
methods: {
  getData() {
   ...
   //Once done
   this.flagA = true
   if (this.flagA == true && this.flagB == true) this.loading = false
  },
  getOtherData() {
   ...
   //Once done
   this.flagB = true
   if (this.flagA == true && this.flagB == true) this.loading = false
  }
...
```

Is there a better approach?

EDIT to show non HTTP function:

```
getOtherData() {
    var request = indexedDB.open("Database", 1);
    request.onerror = event => {
        //IndexedDB is not supported. Resort to fallback option and continue regular program flow
    };
    request.onsuccess = event => {
      this.db = event.target.result;

      var transaction = this.db.transaction(["project"], "readwrite");

      var projectStore = transaction.objectStore("project");
      var projectReq = projectStore.get(1);

      projectReq.onsuccess = () => {
        this.flagB = true;
      };
      projectReq.onerror = () => {
        //error 
      };
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as both functions return a promise, use an `async` lifecycle hook and `Promise.all`.  It works regardless of whether that promise comes from an http request or is just returned from a method:

```js
async mounted() {
  const p1 = axios.get('getData');      // not awaited, just returning promise
  const p2 = this.getOtherData();       // not awaited, just returning promise

  // awaiting both, responses will be in `response1` and `response2`
  const [ response1, response2 ] = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);    
  this.loading = false;
}
```

Make sure that all functions return a promise if you don't use the http promise directly:

```js
getData() {
  ...
  return request;
},
getOtherData() {
   ...
   return request;
}
```

Comment: See my edit. I know this approach for axios but how can I do it for an axios and non anxios function?

Comment: That other function should return a promise and then it can still work the same way.  Try `return request` at the end of `getOtherData`.  I edited to show the hook code for that

Comment: Your solution does not seem to work
https://pastebin.com/wYmgU4HF

Comment: You haven't set the variables you're logging anywhere.  And you're not returning a promise in *either function*.  It should be `return this.$axios...` in `getData` and `return request` at the end of `getOtherData`.  Study the answer carefully

Comment: This should make everything clear:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/wju39z7b/